# Execute Terminal commands in Bash script in sequence mentioned in the file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to create a bash script in MAC which will open the required softwares and also run required commands when I just run this script.
So I put some commands in the file and named it with `.command` extension so that the file will be opened and run automatically by terminal when I double click the file.

I do not have much knowledge on Bash script so I am facing the below 2 issues.

- Issue 1: (Edit: Issue1 is resolved if I put `sleep 15` to make the bash pause for sometime before running the next command)

  When I run the 2 commands manually in sequence then I see that 2 IDE instances are opened with the 2 folder locations. But when I put this is a file and run the file then only the 2nd IDE instance seems to be opened.

  `#!/bin/sh
  open -a "IntelliJ IDEA.app" /app_location/app1
  open -a "IntelliJ IDEA.app" /app_location/app2`

- Issue 2 related to long running commands:

  I want to open multiple tabs in terminal and run various commands. How can I do this.
  I tried as below but since the first command is just a long running command until I manually stop the app so the next command is not run unless I stop the first command. So, how can I open multiple terminal tabs and run commands without waiting for previous command to be completed?

  ```
  osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
  APP_BASE_LOCATION="/somepath"
  cd $APP_BASE_LOCATION/app1
  mvn spring-boot:run

  osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
  APP_BASE_LOCATION="/somepath"
  cd $APP_BASE_LOCATION/app2
  npm start
  ```

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? You can run processes in the background by appending an `&` to the command, like `long-running-command -with -parameters &`

Comment: I am using bash shell in MAC Terminal.. I am not sure about the emulator

Comment: Issue1 is resolved if I put `sleep 15` to make the bash pause for sometime before running the next command

Comment: use osascript/applescript. see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/how-can-i-write-a-script-to-open-multiple-terminal-tabs-and-execute-code-in-them